# Casper Friendly Finality Gadget - Greater degrees of transaction/settlement finality over existing PoW?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper

With Casper Friendly Finality Gadget, can one expect greater degrees of transaction/settlement finality over existing PoW?

Answer (score 0):

[Casper](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/28/understanding-serenity-part-2-casper/) **introduces** *economic finality* to Ethereum. POW does not guarantee finality at all. So yes, there is guaranteed improvement in possibility of finality.

> Another unique component of
>   the way that Casper does things is that rather than consensus being
>   by-chain as is the case with current proof of work protocols,
>   consensus is by-block: the consensus process comes to a decision on
>   the status of the block at each height independently of every other
>   height. This mechanism does introduce some inefficiencies -
>   particularly, a bet must register the validator's opinion on the block
>   at every height rather than just the head of the chain - but it proves
>   to be much simpler to implement strategies for consensus-by-bet in
>   this model, and it also has the advantage that it is much more
>   friendly to high blockchain speed: theoretically, one can even have a
>   block time that is faster than network propagation with this model, as
>   blocks can be produced independently of each other, though with the
>   obvious proviso that block finalization will still take a while
>   longer.
>
> In by-chain consensus, one can view the consensus process as being a
>   kind of tug-of-war between negative infinity and positive infinity at
>   each fork, where the "status" at the fork represents the number of
>   blocks in the longest chain on the right side minus the number of
>   blocks on the left side:
>
> Clients trying to determine the "correct chain" simply move forward
>   starting from the genesis block, and at each fork go left if the
>   status is negative and right if the status is positive. The economic
>   incentives here are also clear: once the status goes positive, there
>   is a strong economic pressure for it to converge to positive infinity,
>   albeit very slowly. If the status goes negative, there is a strong
>   economic pressure for it to converge to negative infinity.
>
> Incidentally, note that under this framework the core idea behind the
>   GHOST scoring rule becomes a natural generalization - instead of just
>   counting the length of the longest chain toward the status, count
>   every block on each side of the fork:
>
> In by-block consensus, there is once again the tug of war, though this
>   time the "status" is simply an arbitrary number that can be increased
>   or decreased by certain actions connected to the protocol; at every
>   block height, clients process the block if the status is positive and
>   do not process the block if the status is negative. Note that even
>   though proof of work is currently by-chain, it doesn't have to be: one
>   can easily imagine a protocol where instead of providing a parent
>   block, a block with a valid proof of work solution must provide a +1
>   or -1 vote on every block height in its history; +1 votes would be
>   rewarded only if the block that was voted on does get processed, and
>   -1 votes would be rewarded only if the block that was voted on does not get processed:
>
> Of course, in proof of work such a design would not work well for one
>   simple reason: if you have to vote on absolutely every previous
>   height, then the amount of voting that needs to be done **will increase
>   quadratically with time and fairly quickly grind the system to a halt**.
>   With consensus-by-bet, however, because the tug of war can converge to
>   complete finality exponentially, the voting overhead is much more
>   tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot reliably and objectively expect greater finality in either systems, as neither can be quantified to a degree that allows meaningful comparison.

Casper aims to provide some form of economic finality by financially punishing byzantine behaviour, while Bitcoin aims to offer probabilistic finality, making a violation of safety statistically unlikely.

Theoretically, Casper should abide to BFT guarantees and provide theoretical consistency if a supermajority is honest, but, in practice, the threshold may require 80%+ honest validators, which may be impossible to prove in a trustless manner, making 100% finality impossible.

> So no quantifiable studies are available?

Not that i'm aware of. Casper should provide their finality guarantees much faster than Bitcoin (which doesn't have a mechanism that is considered "finality" other than the 6 blocks confirmations rule-of-thumb,) but neither are 100% guarantees, so I'm not sure how to quantify which provides "greater degree of finality" that holds invariant of time elapsed and is tractable & applicable in practice.

Comment: Thanks! So no quantifiable studies are available?

Comment: updated my answer